# 2 sic app: value cannot be null

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

After installing 2sic and dragging a 2sic app in a page we get an error when we refresh: "the value cannot be null".
Included are the screenshot and stacktrace.

Version: 8.7.0
Dnn: 8.0.4

[image]

```html
   https://museumkaart.accept.icatt.nl/desktopmodules/2sxc/api/view/Module/GetSelectableApps

StackTrace=   at DotNetNuke.Common.Requires.NotNull(String argName, Object argValue)
   at DotNetNuke.Web.Api.HttpConfigurationExtensions.GetTabAndModuleInfoProviders(HttpConfiguration configuration)
   at DotNetNuke.Web.Api.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.IterateTabAndModuleInfoProviders[T](HttpRequestMessage request, TryMethod`1 func, T fallback)
   at DotNetNuke.Web.Api.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.FindModuleInfo(HttpRequestMessage request)
   at ToSic.SexyContent.WebApi.Helpers.GetSxcOfApiRequest(HttpRequestMessage request) in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\WebApi\Helpers.cs:line 26
   at ToSic.SexyContent.WebApi.SxcApiController.get_SxcContext() in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\WebApi\SxcApiController.cs:line 23
   at ToSic.SexyContent.WebApi.View.ModuleController.get_ContentGroupReferenceManager() in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\WebApi\View\ModuleController.cs:line 28
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a fairly old version of 2sxc it could simply be a bug. You should at least upgrade to 8.12 and test again.